# Android Studio ViewPager with navigation

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have this situation:

`Fragment1` uses `viewPager`, then when click some component inside the `viewPager`'s child fragment, it open `Fragment2`, which also uses `viewPager`.

So far so good. But then, on click the back button, doesn't come back to `Fragment1`, coming back for my main activity instead. The app uses single activity and Android Navigation.

I already tried use `viewPager2`, it happens the same thing.

Thanks if anyone can help me.

```
public class Fragment1 extends AbstractNavFragment {

    private Fragment1 binder;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binder = Fragment1Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binder.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binder.viewPager.setAdapter(new PageAdapterInternal(getChildFragmentManager()));
        binder.viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        binder.tabLayout.getTab().setupWithViewPager(binder.viewPager);
    }

    public void navigateToFragment2() {
        navigate(R.id.action_Fragment1_to_Fragment2);
    }

    private class PageAdapterInternal extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public PageAdapterInternal(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new IrcSupplyPositionsFragment(IrcSupplyPositionsFragment.FragmentType.PENDING);
                case 1:
                    return new IrcSupplyPositionsFragment(IrcSupplyPositionsFragment.FragmentType.COMPLETED);
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + position);
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return translate("rotativeInventory.supply.pendingPositions");
                case 1:
                    return translate("rotativeInventory.supply.positionsCompleted");
                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Fragment2 extends AbstractNavFragment {

    private Fragment2 binder;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binder = Fragment2Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binder.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binder.viewPager.setAdapter(new RotativeInventorySupplyUDFragment.PageAdapterInternal(getChildFragmentManager()));
        binder.viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        binder.tabLayout.getTab().setupWithViewPager(binder.viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doOnViewCreate() {}

    private class PageAdapterInternal extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public PageAdapterInternal(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new IrcSupplyUDFragment(IrcSupplyUDFragment.FragmentType.PENDING);
                case 1:
                    return new IrcSupplyUDFragment(IrcSupplyUDFragment.FragmentType.COMPLETED);
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + position);
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return translate("rotativeInventory.supply.pendingPositions");
                case 1:
                    return translate("rotativeInventory.supply.positionsCompleted");
                default:
                    return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override your `onBackPressed` method of your Activity, to controll all this stuff or register your fragment for a [OnBackPressedDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher) and when user click on back button of your device, take a decision, like ==> `findNavController().popBackStack()`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much friend!